# How to connect Samsung Galaxy Watch active with my android app?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, watch, tizen

[I have this Samsung-watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktjMX.jpg)

I implemented a mobile application for my graduation project, it is a triaging system  that will serve the people who has an injury or illness, 
In some cases we need to ask the patient about his heart rate, we want to take this data from the watch instead of asking him about it.

I searched for this and founded that I need to install Tizen extension to the visual studio, I want to write a code that take heart rate, then connect this code to my android application,

Does anyone know or can help me to do this?

Does anyone know the steps that i would follow to complete this process ?

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow isn't here to help you with your project by doing code for you. It's here to answer questions about your already existing code and helping you fix it if it has some propblems.

Comment: I want Steps to follow  , I dont need code , I want to know where to  start  !

Comment: @LaiLaAlQam Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will find a lot of help from [Samsung Developer Site](https://developer.samsung.com/).

Check below link:
[Samsung Developers - Creating Your First App](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch/develop/creating-your-first-app/net-companion/setup-sdk)

May the force be with you.

Answer (score 0):

**How to create Pulsometer application for wearable:**

http://tizenschool.org/tutorial/166/contents/1

then, for example, You can use **Samsung Accessory Protocol** to communicate wearable with android device:

https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory

https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory/guide

or implement other way of data exchange, for example **uploading data to remote server**:

[How to make HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request)